# Only the first test is actually run in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have the following code:

```
describe("Player", function() {

    var player;

    beforeEach(function(){
        player = new Player({
            name: "Mark"
        });
    });

  it("has a name", function() {
      expect(player.name).toEqual("Mark");
  });

  it("has a score"), function() {
        expect(player.score).toEqual(0);
  };

});
```

Jasmine says it's passing 2 specs, even though `player.score` is `undefined`

If I do...

```
  it("has a score"), function() {
       console.log("hello")
       expect(player.score).toEqual(0);
  };
```

I can see the second test is never run. Any ideas why? (this is my first time using Jasmine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misplaced closing parenthesis in the second spec (`it()` call). It should read:

```
it("has a score", function() {
    expect(player.score).toEqual(0);
});
```

I run into this issue a lot: syntax errors in Jasmine specs result in tests not even running, rather than failing as they should. (I believe there [may be an outstanding bug against Jasmine for this](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/pull/45).)